# In ConfigParser how to get only section-local options?

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

Consider the following MWE named `foo.py`:

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from configparser import ConfigParser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    with open("foo.ini") as ini:
        cfg.read_file(ini)
    for section in cfg.sections():
        print("[%s]" % (section))
        for option, value in cfg.items(section):
            print("%s = %s" % (option, value))
```

... and the accompanying `foo.ini`:

```
[DEFAULT]
basedir = /foo/bar
sourcedir = %(basedir)s/baz

[task:1]
sourcedir = /usr
workdir = %(sourcedir)s/src

[task:2]
hdrdir = %(sourcedir)s/include
```

The script will yield the following when run:

```
[task:1]
basedir = /foo/bar
sourcedir = /usr
workdir = /usr/src
[task:2]
basedir = /foo/bar
sourcedir = /foo/bar/baz
hdrdir = /foo/bar/baz/include
```

The desired outcome is to iterate exclusively over the (interpolated) options (via `ConfigParser.items()`) *local to the given section*.

Passing `raw=True` to `ConfigParser.items()` doesn't affect the list of items other than that the values are *not* being interpolated (which is anyway not the desired outcome).

Now I could do something like in this modified version of the initial script:

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from configparser import ConfigParser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    with open("foo.ini") as ini:
        cfg.read_file(ini)
    print("; sections: %s" % (cfg.sections()))
    print("; defaults: %s" % (cfg.defaults()))
    for section in cfg.sections():
        print("[%s]" % (section))
        print("; options = %s" % (cfg.options(section)))
        for option, value in cfg.items(section):
            if option in cfg.defaults():
                # can't use cfg.defaults()[option] ... that's the raw value
                if cfg[cfg.default_section][option] == value:
                    continue
            print("%s = %s" % (option, value))
```

... which yields:

```
; sections: ['task:1', 'task:2']
; defaults: OrderedDict([('basedir', '/foo/bar'), ('sourcedir', '%(basedir)s/baz')])
[task:1]
; options = ['sourcedir', 'workdir', 'basedir']
sourcedir = /usr
workdir = /usr/src
[task:2]
; options = ['hdrdir', 'basedir', 'sourcedir']
hdrdir = /foo/bar/baz/include
```

So it'll work at first glance, but would filter out section-local options which have a value identical to the global one of the same name.

Now this may seem only like a cosmetic issue, but in my case there is a semantic difference, still, between whether the option exists locally inside a section or whether its value was inherited from the default section (think multiple files, multiple inherited options ...). Point being that this is a naïve approach which doesn't work for me.

**So the question:** how can I get *just* the options that are really inside a section of an `.ini` file, without all those global inherited options?
Is there a way to do this without reaching into the guts of the `configparser` module and tampering with non-public methods and stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the [code of `ConfigParser`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/configparser.py) I don't see a public API to do it. Indeed, any method in `ConfigParser` extends the given section with defaults.

The only straightfoward way I see would be to change the default section <s>either in your config or</s> in [`ConfigParser` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser) (`default_section` argument):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cfg = ConfigParser(default_section=None)
# (...)
```

However the side effect is that the automatic "default" mechanism will not work any more for this instanciated `ConfigParser`. However you can still do the fallback mechanism your self:

```py
cfg = ConfigParser(default_section=None)
cfg.get(mysection, myoption, fallback=cfg.get('DEFAULT', myoption))
```

Also, the interpolation in values will not work from `DEFAULT` section. But you can use [`ExtendedInterpolation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation).

Full example:

```py
# test.py
from configparser import ConfigParser, DEFAULTSECT, ExtendedInterpolation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = ConfigParser(default_section=None, interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())

    with open('test.ini') as ini:
        cfg.read_file(ini)

    for section in cfg.sections():
        if section == DEFAULTSECT:
            continue

        print('[%s]' % (section))
        for key, value in cfg.items(section):
            print('%s = %s' % (key, value))
```

```
# test.ini
[DEFAULT]
foo=bar

[section]
key="value ${DEFAULT:foo}"
```

Edits:

- Rename `DEFAULT` section is not a good idea if the purpose of it is to configure default values. I strike this option.
- Set `default_section` as `None` instead of `"whatever"`
- Add a full code example
- Add details about ExtendedInterpolation